# How to convert output from Python after sudo command from <type> int to <type> str?

Tags: python, macos, sudo

I have the following code to receive list of process with sudo:

```
sudoPass = 'mypass'
command = "launchctl list | grep -v com.apple"
x = os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudoPass, command))
```

But, I receive answer in  int. I need in str. Is it possible to convert it to str without loosing data?

Comment: `os.system` doesn't intercept output to stdout.  The return value is the exit status, which is an int.  The data type isn't the issue.  Use the `subprocess` module if you want to capture the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.system returns (in most cases, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) the exit value of the process. Meaning most of the time 0 is everything went fine.

What you look for is the subprocess module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) that allow you to capture output like so :

```
import subprocess
sudoPass = 'mypass\n' #Note the new line
command = "launchctl list | grep -v com.apple"
x = subprocess.Popen('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudoPass, command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = x.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

Comment: I can't use it. I received <subprocess.Popen object at .....>

Comment: Also, it doesn't use pass at all.

Comment: Please see edited answer above. In short, the Popen object contains the output of the command for stdout and stderr.